# How to get a random array of file Arrays in Android?

Tags: android

How to get a random array of file `Arrays` in Android?

```
<string-array name="a1">
    <item name="id"> a1</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="a2">
    <item name="id"> a2</item>
</string-array>
```

I want to programmatically select a random array

Answer (score 0):

Get the array resource id in array of integers

<strike>int[] arrayIds=new int[]{R.array.a1,R.array.a1};</strike>

Use java's random method to generate the random number

```
 Random random=new Random();
```

Specify the min max random numbers to generated in the range of .in this case it is between 0,1 inclusive

```
int randomIndex=random.nextInt(0,1);
```

Use the random number generated to choose from index if array

<strike>String[] values=getResources().getStringArray(arrayIds[randomIndex]);</strike>

**UPDATE**

// Use this code to get the dynamic array without have a local mapping of ID
 int res = getResources().getIdentifier("a"+randomIndex, "id", getPackageName());

String[] values=getResources().getStringArray(res);

Comment: Could you explain how/why your code works? That'll enable the OP and others to understand and apply your methods (where applicable) elsewhere. Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/284827) and liable to be deleted. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10378633)

Comment: I need it here  `R.array.a1` randomly selected

Comment: Something similar to `a+rnd.nextInt(10)`